# Proving $ (A - B) ∩ C = (A ∩ C) - B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am attempting to prove the following:

$(A - B) ∩ C = (A ∩ C) - B$

My construction of my solution is as follows:

$(A - B) = A ∩ B^c$

Then,

$(A ∩ B^c ) ∩ C$ is equivalent to $(A \cap C) \cap B^c$ by associativity

Looking at the right hand side, we have $(A ∩ C) - B$ which is equivalent to 
$(A ∩ C) ∩ B^c $

Then, $(A ∩ C) ∩ B^c = (A ∩ C) ∩ B^c$

Is this correct? It doesn't seem to rigorous to me, but I'm unsure of another way to prove it. Thanks!

Comment: Your proof is okay if it is made clear at forehand what complements of sets (like $B^c$) exactly stand for. In this case you could take $X:=A\cup B\cup C$ and $U^c:=X-U$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are allowed to use $A - B = A \cap B^c$ then yes this proof isn't too bad and your work looks correct. You could also prove this with set-builder notation.

$$(A-B)\cap C = \{x:(x \in A) \wedge (x \notin B) \wedge (x \in C)\} \\ \iff  \{x:(x \in A \wedge x \in C)\wedge (x \notin B) \} \\ \iff  (A \cap C) - B$$

Answer (score 1):

After you conclude that, by associativity (AND commutativity), we have $(\dagger)$ $$\begin{align} (A - B) ∩ C &= (A\cap B^c)\cap C\\ & = A\cap B^c\cap C  \\ &= (A\cap C)\cap B^c\end{align}$$ Note that this is in turn equivalent to $$(A\cap C) - B,$$

(which is the right-hand side of what you are to prove is equivalent to the LHS) and you are done! You will then have shown that $$(A - B)\cap C = (A\cap C) - B$$

Comment: (+1) This is pretty much what I was going to put: both are equal to $A\cap B^C\cap C$ because $\cap$ commutes and associates with itself.

Comment: What is $B^c$? Yes, I know: the *complement* of $B$. But this asks for a definition of the "universe" wich still lacks.

Comment: @vera Universe is adequately represented by $A \cup\ B \cup C$ for this proof (which I see now you already proposed on a comment to the question :-) )

Answer (score 0):

$(a - b) ∩ c = (a ∩ c) - b$

The setminus operator indicates that an element is in one set **AND** not in another.

If $x\in a$ and $x \not\in b$ and $x \in c$ then $x \in a$ and $x \in c$ but not in $b$.

Now, prove the reverse.